# Rendering a specific region of a BufferedGraphics buffer

Tags: c#, gdi+

I need to render a large PDF document into a Windows form control. For this to be performant, it would make sense to prerender the entire PDF into a graphics buffer and then blit the relevant part of that buffer in OnPaint.

However, BufferedGraphics.Render does not accept any arguments other than the target Graphics. How can I make it only render a certain region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the bounding Clip on the Graphics

[MSDN Graphics.Clip Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clip(v=vs.110).aspx)

Another option is to Import the old BitBlt function.

Comment: It did end up becoming necessary to use BitBlt